# Modify a function to ignore any clicks made in the last cell of each row of a table

Tags: javascript

I'm using this JavaScript function that works as follows. When you click on any row in the table, it opens a new page at link specified on line 6. (The ID# from column 0 is added to the end of the link) It works perfectly, but now I need it to ignore clicks made in the last cell of each row. I'm trying to put another link in that last cell and as long as this function is active it opens the link on line 6 and ignores the link in the last cell of the row. i starts at 2 because of the table header. How can I modify the function, such that, it does not respond to clicks in the last cell of each row?

````
function addRowHandlers(){
        var rows = document.getElementById("mytable").rows;
        for (i = 2; i < rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].onclick = function(){ return function(){
                var id = this.cells[0].innerHTML; 
                window.open("https://site url/"+id+";", "Details", "top=150, left=500,height=757, width=900");   
            };}(rows[i]); }}
        window.onload = addRowHandlers();```
````

Comment: maybe just `for (i = 2; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {`

Comment: When I tried that, it simply stopped working for the last row of the table. rows.length must refer to the total number of rows, not the number of cells in each row.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i misreaded your question, i would bind onclick event on cells instead of rows then like this:

```
function addRowHandlers(){
    var rows = document.getElementById("mytable").rows;
    for (i = 2; i < rows.length; i++) {
        //edit: let instead of var
        let id = rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
        for (j = 0; j < rows[i].cells.length - 1/* last one is not included */; j++) {
            rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function(){
                window.open("https://site url/"+id+";", "Details", "top=150, left=500,height=757, width=900");   
            };
        }
    }
}

window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a common class name to all the last cells of each row.so that based on the class name you can identify the last cells and avoid the window.open function for the cells that have an class name mentioned by you.

please refer the below the modified code.

```
    for (i = 2; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].onclick = function(){ return function(){
            for(var j = 0 ; j<=this.cells.length; j++) {
                if(!this.cells[j].classList.contains('your className of last cell for each row') { 
                    var id = this.cells[0].innerHTML; 
                    window.open("https://site url/"+id+";", "Details", "top=150, 
                    left=500,height=757, width=900");
                }
    }   
 
    window.onload = addRowHandlers();`
```